# Image is not validating: "The avatar must be an image"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using a modal to preview an avatar. The even that triggers the modal is outside the ability to have a parent child structure so I have to pass the file object to my UpdateAvatar component.

**Html**

```
<avatar-update :image-blob="avatarFile" :show="avatarModalShow" 
               @close="avatarModalShow = !avatarModalShow" 
               :change-avatar="updateCrop"> </avatar-update>
```

**Root Instance**

```
data() {
    return {
        avatarModalShow: false,
        avatarFile: null,
    }
},

methods: {
    onFileChange: function(e) {
        this.avatarFile = e.target.files[0];
        this.avatarModalShow = !this.avatarModalShow;
  },
},
```

**AvatarUpdate**

```
export default {
    props: ['show','imgUrl','changeAvatar','imageBlob'],
    data() {
      return {
        image: null,
        message: null,
        internalImageObj: null
      }
    },
    watch: {
      changeAvatar: function(){     
          this.image = this.imgUrl;
      },
      imageBlob: function (newVal) {
        let reader  = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(newVal)
        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          this.internalImageObj = reader.result
        }, false)  
      }
    },
    updated: function () {
      this.image = this.imgUrl;      
    },
    methods: {
        close: function(){
          this.$emit('close');
        },

        submitAvatar: function(){


          const avatarFormData = new FormData();
          avatarFormData.append('avatar', this.internalImageObj);
          console.log(avatarFormData);

          axios({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/profile/avatar',
              data: avatarFormData,
          }).then(function (response) {


          this.message = "Your avatar has been submitted";   

          }.bind(this))
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
public function avatar(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'image',
    ]);

    return $request->all();
}
```

When I `return $request->all();` in the avatar function with no validation on the UserController I'm getting this output: `avatar:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhSomeLongString`

**Error**

> {message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {avatar: ["The avatar must be an image."]}}
>   errors
>   :
>   {avatar: ["The avatar must be an image."]}
>   avatar
>   :
>   ["The avatar must be an image."]
>   0
>   :
>   "The avatar must be an image."
>   message
>   :
>   "The given data was invalid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because your validation rule for `avatar` is `image` or `mimes:jpeg,bmp,png` this it will look for a file where the mime type is jpeg,bmp,png. but in your case your `axios` send it as a base64 which don't have a mime type. you need to include `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` header in your axios object like this,

```
axios({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/profile/avatar',
   data: avatarFormData,
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
 })
```

hope this helps.

Comment: How would I go about using the formData interface approach? I'm already using formData to pass to axios. So I'm unsure how to continue on.

Comment: I am still getting a base64 image

Comment: are you using a cropper? `avatarFormData.append('avatar', this.internalImageObj);` you are appeding base64 not a file here. `this,imgUrl` has the file so you need to append that `avatarFormData.append('avatar', this.imgUrl);`

Comment: I think something is going on since I am getting the file output when I log it to the console, but when I send it through axios it passes validation, but I get an empty object in chromes network tools `{avatar: {}}avatar:{}`. I'll try and store the image and get back to you.

Comment: Just tried what you said in the comments, but didn't use imgUrl. This is what worked:

```avatarFormData.append('avatar', this.imageBlob);```